# EDIT: Proving $f^{-1}(f(C))=C$

Tags: proof-writing

I need to prove that $f^{-1}(f(C))=C$.

This are the informations. There exists two sets A and B, and function $f(A)\to B$.

I don't know how to solve this, and I tried to search google, but I didn't find anything useful.

Please help. Thanks!!

EDIT: I forgot to add that function is bijective

Comment: The equation in the title is false in general. Do you know anything else about $f$?

Comment: No, I wrote all I know about this assingment

Comment: Could you include the exact question from the assignment?

Comment: As a counterexample, you can take $A = B = \mathbf{R}$, $f:x \mapsto x^2$, $Z = [0;1]$.

Comment: construct instances (explicit examples) and see

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I can but it is on german language

Comment: @depecheSoul Do it. If needed, someone will surely help translate or answer directly.

Comment: Now, this makes sense that $f^{-1}(f(C))=C$

Comment: @NasuSama for me also, but I need to prove it and I don't know how.

Comment: @depecheSoul We, the users, want you to show some thoughts for this problem, even if you can't proceed.

Comment: Look at Michael Albanese's answer.  For this type of problem, when you want to show something is equal, in set theory we show that one is the subset of another, and likewise another is the subset of one (in Layman's terms).

Comment: Now that we know that $f$ is bijective, we should ask what $f^{-1}(D)$ means for a subset $D$ of $B$. How is that defined?

Comment: For every element $x$ from $A$ it is valid that $y=f(x)\implies x=f^{-1}(y)$, and for $x\in B$, so now I have that $f^{-1}(f(x))=f^{-1}(y)=x$, and now I have to do the same for $x\in B$. Am I on right track. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a somewhat bigger hint, in a different style than you may be used to.

First, which elements $\;x\;$ does the set $\;f^{-1}[f[C]]\;$ contain?  Let's use the basic properties and calculate:
\begin{align}
& x \in f^{-1}[f[C]] \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"basic property of $\;\cdot^{-1}[\cdot]\;$: $\;x \in f^{-1}[W] \;\equiv\; f(x) \in W\;$"} \\
& f(x) \in f[C] \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"basic property of $\;\cdot[\cdot]\;$: $\;y \in f[V] \;\equiv\; \langle \exists x : x \in V : f(x) = y \rangle\;$"} \\
& \langle \exists z : z \in C : f(z) = f(x) \rangle \\
\text{...} & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"..."} \\
\end{align}

Now we want to end this calculation with $\;x \in C\;$ (why?), and there are two ways to continue it:
\begin{align}
& \langle \exists z : z \in C : f(z) = f(x) \rangle \\
\Leftarrow & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"choose a specific $\;z\;$ that gets us near our goal..."} \\
& \text{...} \\
\end{align}
and also
\begin{align}
& \langle \exists z : z \in C : f(z) = f(x) \rangle \\
\Rightarrow & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"assume $\;f\;$ has some specific property to achieve our goal..."} \\
& \text{...} \\
\end{align}

How do you complete the calculations?  What property of $\;f\;$ do you need?  What is your conclusion?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Show that $f^{-1}(f(C)) \subseteq C$ and $f^{-1}(f(C)) \supseteq C$. One of these is true for any $f$, while the other relies on the fact that $f$ is bijective (in fact, you just need $f$ to be injective).

Comment: Because $ f^{-1}(f(x))\subset C\ and\ f^{-1}(f(x))\supset C$ is a definition of subsets equality,can I write that $f^{-1}(f(C))=f^{-1}(f(C))$ and go from there??? Thanks

Comment: What is $x$ and why are the two subset relationships true? Note that $f^{-1}(f(C))$ and $C$ are two sets. To show $f^{-1}(f(C)) \subseteq C$, you need to show that every element of $f^{-1}(f(C))$ is an element of $C$.

Comment: I tried to solve it something like this: For every element $x$ from $A$ it is valid that $y=f(x)\implies x=f^{-1}(y)$, and for $x\in B$, so now I have that $f^{-1}(f(x))=f^{-1}(y)=x$, and now I have to do the same for $x\in B$. Am I on right track. Thanks for helping me!!

Comment: First of all, that implication requires justification. Once you have justified it, you have shown that $f^{-1}(f(x)) = x$. Which of the two subset relationships does this help you to prove?

Comment: What do you mean by justification?

Comment: I mean that you should say $y = f(x)$ implies $x = f^{-1}(y)$ because $f$ is a bijection.